# something gone wrong with my wordpress site - virus?

Tags: php, wordpress, server, virus

I have a wordpress website on my server. I bought a theme via ThemeForest and uploaded it.

Today (after few days the site was running) when I surf to the site this is what the browser shows (image)[image]

I have no idea what it is, I searched little in the files but didn't come to anything...

the link to the [website](http://www.timorvoice1.co.il)

anyone have seen something like this before? any ideas?

Comment: you have been hacked, remove every file, clear your database, reset passwords.

Comment: Yes I got this hack too.. few month ago. If you have a SHELL access you can search for it. Your database shouln'd be hacked. It is just one file with the 'bad' code.

Comment: That bad code is in your `wp-config.php` file. And you **really** need to change every password and check every files.

Comment: What theme are you using? It could responsible. What web host are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**Reinstalling WordPress after a Hack**

1. First you'll want to [download the latest version of WordPress](http://wordpress.org/download/) to
   your local computer.
2. Extract the files in the **.zip** archive you downloaded to a local
   folder.
3. Using FTP, upload all of the folders and files contained within the **wordpress** directory to your **public_html** directory. Or if your domain was an addon domain and its document root was in a sub-directory make sure you're uploading it there. You can do this by hitting **Ctrl-A** in your FTP client when you're in the left-hand pane to select all the files, then simply drag them onto the server.
4. Once the files are done uploading, navigate to the **quarantine** directory on the server side, right-click on **wp-config.php** and choose **View/Edit**. Your FTP application should prompt you for what application you'd like to open the file with, you can just use a text editor such as **Notepad**. Then finally copy down the database information from the **define('DB_...)** sections.
5. At this point if you try to simply access the site you'll get a WordPress error about no **wp-config.php** file.
6. Back in your FTP client, navigate to your **public_html** directory and you should see a file called **wp-config-sample.php**, right-click on this file and choose **View/Edit**, open the file in **Notepad** then fill in your database name, database user, and database user password.
   Then hit **Ctrl-S** to save the file, in a few seconds your FTP client should prompt you if you'd like to save this back to the server, click Yes. You can also place a check beside Finish editing and delete local file if your FTP client gives you that option
7. Now in your FTP client right-click on **wp-config-sample.php** choose Rename, and then name the file just **wp-config.php**.
8. Now in this case if we try to go to our site again it's an all blank page, the reason for this is because our site used a custom theme, and those theme files are still quarantined. So next in your FTP client navigate to the **/quarantine/wp-content/themes** directory, and drag over the **pinboard** directory (or whichever theme you used) to your local computer.
9. Now navigate on the server side to the **/public_html/wp-content/themes directory**, and then drag the pinboard directory from the local computer to the server.

Comment: Uplod all table and every thing

Answer (score 0):

Your website is hacked. Now you have to remove all backdoors created by the hackers. And follow everything in this guide
https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked